# va_list initialization in different architecture

Tags: c++, gcc, standards, solaris

```
  va_list args = 0;
```

I found a code in my application as above, and it is compiling properly  in following gcc version.

```
~ $ /usr/sfw/bin/gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/sfw/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/3.4.3/specs
Configured with: /sfw10/builds/build/sfw10-patch/usr/src/cmd/gcc/gcc-3.4.3/configure --prefix=/usr/sfw --with-as=/usr/ccs/
bin/as --without-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --without-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
```

But when i compiled the same code in new machine, it is giving issue since the va_list args is initialized with zero. Hope va_list is typedef of something and i removed the initialization of va_list with zero and it is compiled fine in new machine.

But fortunately both old and new machine has same gcc version.

```
    NEW MACHINE GCC VERSION:
    Reading specs from /usr/sfw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.4.3/specs
Configured with: /builds/sfw10-gate/usr/src/cmd/gcc/gcc-3.4.3/configure --prefix=/usr/sfw --with-as=/usr/sfw/bin/gas --with-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --without-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
```

But i noticed that architecture of two machine is different. Is that causing any issue.

Since stdarg is an standard library. So why it is varying based on architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since stdarg is an standard library. So why it is varying based on architecture?

Yes, it's standard, but it can only be used in the officially supported ways, and initialisation using `0` is not one of those ways.

`va_list` is not special in that respect, there are plenty of types and functions that are standard, but have implementation variations in their handling of invalid uses. A trivial example is `printf(0);`, which may silently work and do nothing on some implementations, but crash badly at runtime on others.

Unfortunately there isn't any fool-proof checker for invalid programs that happen to be accepted on your particular platform, nor can there be.

Comment: I thought like since gcc is implementor for both architecture, they will do the same implementation in both machines. I wonder, whether implemenation of gcc will vary from one machine to other. This is first time i am noticing

Comment: @VinothKumar Argument passing rules vary from architecture to architecture, some more complex than others, and gcc needs to follow the rules set by the architecture designers. On SPARC, it's kind of complex, and `va_list` is a struct. You can't assign a scalar like `0` to a struct. Maybe the standards committee could be asked to provide something like a `va_list_null` value to satisfy programming standards that mandate initialization of all variables.

Answer (score 3):

`va_list` should never be initialized.  It's standard in C and C++ that it is just left uninitialized until `va_start()` is called.

Your old code was broken.  Just remove the `=0` regardless of which platform you're on, and try again.